# Should specific filters be expressed as an explicitly named field, or a generic field with a filter param?

Tags: graphql

When expressing data filters, via GraphQL, should we be creating explicitly-named fields for that filter or should we be adding a parameter to a more generic list-type field that would apply the filter?

For example, if I've got a field called `teams` but I want to provide the ability to filter the data, provided by `teams`, down to only the teams who are active (versus inactive), should I expose that filter via GraphQL as a param on the `teams` field, or should I create a new field called `activeTeams`?

I'm thinking the clearly, explicitly named fields might scale better and be less confusing in the long run because there won't be questions about how params works when paired with each other, etc.

I wanted to get feedback on how maybe Facebook approaches this, or how others are doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the filter as a param on the `teams` field as this is the more scalable approach. Introducing a new filter means only a single parameter needs adding. Whereas the multiple-fields approach requires an exponential number of fields for each possible combination.

Don't forget that you can also alias fields on the client if you wish to fetch multiple queries of teams within the same component:

```
query on Viewer {
  activeTeams: teams(active: true) { ... }
  inactiveTeams: teams(active: false) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't the same be said about params too, though? If you have a lot of filters, then you have to tackle the understanding of how multiple filters apply when mixed with other filters, etc? I'm just thinking out loud here. Perhaps this comes down to mostly opinion. I guess an issue with specific fields would be that you wouldn't have the option to combine multiple filters at all, though.

Comment: You have to understand how multiple filters combine regardless. Even if you have a field for each combination, how do you know which field you require if you can't figure out how the filters will combine?

Comment: I don't think there's any One Truly Right way to do this, although in my experience of the Facebook schema I've seen us use both, with parametrization being more common. This has worked quite well for us.